# Using list inside Android Dialog - how to avoid static?

Tags: java, android, static, dialog

I have an activity which uses a `DialogFragment`. It is my first time implementing a Dialog, so I am creating this dialog using `newInstance` (as recommended in multiple guides) which needs to be static; hence, my `DialogFragment` is also static.

I use a `List<String>` to store and populate the Dialog but to do so, requires me to have this List declared too as static inside the activity. Afaik, it is bad practice to hold static variables in Java. So can I avoid it in my case? How?

In other words, how can I pass data from my activity to the dialog without it being static? Note that I need to modify this List quite often.

I create the Dialog as following:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
PickDisplayDialogFragment alertDialog = PickDisplayDialogFragment.newInstance("Displays");
alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
```

And my newInstance looks like:

```
public static PickDisplayDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
    PickDisplayDialogFragment frag = new PickDisplayDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(DIALOG_TITLE, title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
```

Edit: I get the list with getList() and use it (by converting to array) with dialog.setItems():

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString(DIALOG_TITLE);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        alertDialogBuilder.setItems(getList(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                createIntentViewDisplay(which);
            }
        });
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }
```

Comment: Could you, please, expose the place where you would like to use `List<String>`

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ of course, edited the question. Note that in getList() I convert the list into an array so that I can use it in setItems()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use put the strings into the Bundle, using putStringArrayList() function.
[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

Comment: But the bundle is created inside newInstance, which is inside the DialogFragment. My List is outside, in the activity. Why so? Because I first get the data from a server through an AsyncTask; data which I store inside this List.

Comment: Actually, you do have a point; just add it as parameter into newInstance. I'll try it out tomorrow.